# Read a list and add them to curl with different domains

Tags: bash, list, curl, sequence

I have a list of URLs which I want to test some headers on in sequence. For example, I have the following headers:

```
X-Forwarded-For:
X-Forwarded-Host:
```

And there are the following URLs:

```
https://example.com/
https://target.com/
https://redacted.com/
```

I want to add the first header `X-Forwarded-For:` to curl and run it over all URLs in sequence, then add the second header `X-Forwarded-Host:` to curl and run curl over URLs and so on and so forth.

```
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://example.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-For: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://target.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-For: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://redacted.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-For: myserver.com"

curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://example.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-Host: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://target.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-Host: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://redacted.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-Host: myserver.com"
```

I wrote the following code:

```
function myfunc {

    if [[ -f "allurls.txt" ]]; then

        headers_list=("X-Forwarded-For: "
                    "X-Forwarded-Host: "
                    )

        for headers in $(cat "allurls.txt"); do

            for curlme in ${headers_list[@]}; do
                (
                curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url "$headers" -H "$curlme myserver.com"
                )
            done

        done
    fi
}
myfunc
```

The problem with my code is that it executes curl like this:

```
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://example.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-For: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://example.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-Host: myserver.com"

curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://target.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-For: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://target.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-Host: myserver.com"

curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://redacted.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-For: myserver.com"
curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url https://redacted.com/ -H "X-Forwarded-Host: myserver.com"
```

Comment: swap the `for` loops. make the inner the outer and the outer the inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the `for` loops making the inner loop the outer and vice-versa

```
...
        # swap these 2 lines
        for curlme in ${headers_list[@]}; do

            for headers in $(cat "allurls.txt"); do
...
```

PS: I believe the variable names got mixed and this might be more readable and what you expect

```
...
        # swap these 2 lines
        for header in ${headers_list[@]}; do

            for curlme in $(cat "allurls.txt"); do
                curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url "$curlme" -H "$header myserver.com"
...
```

---

**Making an addition for a more natural *nix script**
*aka pro-moves*

```
...
            # it's common to use while-read loops with files
            while read curlme; do
                curl --silent -I --max-time 10 --url "$curlme" -H "$header myserver.com"
            done < allurls.txt
...
```

Comment: Great, Thank You!

Comment: @sof31 take a look at the addition made. always good to know an additional technique it two :)